# Why is a git prompt showing up in my cmd.exe window when I execute a shell script?

Tags: git, cmd

When I execute a shell script---any shell script in any directory---I get a "Welcome to git" greeting.  It doesn't seem to do anything (the script runs as expected), but it is weird, and I want to understand where it is coming from.

For example, here I have a shell script that echos a short string, and this is what I see:
[image: screenshot]

This is vanilla cmd.exe (on a system with UnixUtils installed).  I do use git in other directories, but not here.   What could be happening?

Comment: Invoking *.sh runs the bash instance installed with git. If you check your user profile folder (~ directory), the "welcome to git" message is probably echo'd in your .bashrc file which is executed when bash starts.

Comment: @WesleyWiser - move your comment into answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, just with any other file on Windows, when you try to execute it, Windows will try to invoke its standard file handler. If the bash shipped with msysgit was set up for `.sh` files (which it isn’t by default), then the output would be exactly as you showed.

The output being displayed is stored in `<msysgit-folder>\etc\motd` which is loaded by the shell profile located at `<msysgit-folder>\etc\profile`.

You can also get rid of all the Git specific stuff by changing the Bash to startup without the `--login` parameter (which is supplied by default in the Git Bash shortcut). You might need to adjust your registry to change that in the `.sh` file handler though.

Comment: Bingo.   I had looked for a `.bashrc` or similar file in my home directory and there wasn't one.   But `c:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc\profile` and `motd` are exactly there.   Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are calling Bash scripts directly, that is

```
foo.sh
```

rather than

```
bash foo.sh
```

leads me to believe that you are actually running Bash rather than `cmd.exe`. Having said that you can check you [startup files](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) like this

```sh
grep 'Welcome to Git' /etc/profile ~/.bash_profile ~/.profile ~/.bashrc
```